# How to use my new custom web part in the page type transformation?

Tags: kentico

I have created few web part, now I want to use it in the page type transformation.

How can I use my newly created web part in the page type transformation with transformation type Text/XML?

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge it is not possible to add controls in Text/XML. 
See an earlier post:  http://devnet.kentico.com/questions/register-a-control-in-text-xml-transformation

I think you can either change it to ASCX or write a Macro for this which you can add inside your Text/XML as they suggested before in that post but I have not done this myself.

See https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/miscellaneous-custom-development-tasks/adding-custom-code-to-portal-engine-page-templates on how to add a custom control to your Portal Engine page template.